# Read data from df and pass values in for loop in Databricks

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark, databricks

I am new to both databricks and python,
I have a requirement where in I have two data frames one is Raw_data and other one is val_data (sample image attached).
[val_data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyLpN.jpg)

[Raw_data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM3pC.jpg)

Now val_data df will tell us what validations needs to be done for each column in Raw_data df.

For example let's say in val_data df we see column **Entity_set** thats the column names in Raw_data and then **validation_type**, **condition** defines the action to b done on those  column names in Raw_data .

Now i want to tel the function to check val_data df and then perform what ever action is mentioned in val_data df for that perticular column and record the same in Raw_data df in last colum  ex below

```
If raw_data.Identifier.isnull()
   Then  raw_data.comments == 1
   Else raw_data.comments== 0
```

Please help me on ,how will the function read the column name from val_data df and tell the function what actions to be done

Thanks in advance

I tried some. For loops but had no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the below dataset for data validation.

Validation data:

```
+------+----------+---------------+---------+
|Entity|Entity_Set|Validation_Type|Condition|
+------+----------+---------------+---------+
|ADT   |identifier|Null_Check     |NotNull  |
|ADT   |identifier|Format_Check   |isNum    |
|ADT   |emr_name  |Format_Check   |isStr    |
+------+----------+---------------+---------+
```

Raw Data:

```
+------------+----------+--------+--------+
|entityFamily|identifier|emr_name|comments|
+------------+----------+--------+--------+
|1           |8881      |emr_1   |null    |
|2           |8882      |emr_2   |null    |
+------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

*Note: I have used a function for validating each column and based on the results, I have updated the "Comments" column with 0 and 1.*

Before that lets create some UDFs based on validation you have:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

is_null_udf = udf(lambda value: 1 if value == None else 0)
is_digit_udf = udf(lambda value: 0 if str(value).isdigit() else 1)
is_string_udf = udf(lambda value: 0 if isinstance(value, str) else 1)
```

Lets see how each segment works:

**1. Fetches all validation of a given entity**

```
entity_validations = val_df.filter(col("Entity") == entity).drop("Entity").collect()
```

Output looks like:

```
+----------+---------------+---------+
|Entity_Set|Validation_Type|Condition|
+----------+---------------+---------+
|identifier|Null_Check     |NotNull  |
|identifier|Format_Check   |isNum    |
|emr_name  |Format_Check   |isStr    |
+----------+---------------+---------+
```

**2. Reformat all the fetched records into a python dictionary**

```
column_validations = {}

for row in entity_validations:
    row_dict = row.asDict()
    val_column, val_type, val_condition = [row_dict[key] for key in row_dict]

    if val_column not in column_validations:
        column_validations[val_column] = []
    
    column_validations[val_column].append({'type': val_type, 'condition': val_condition})
```

Output looks like:

```
'identifier': [
    {'type': 'Null_Check', 'condition': 'NotNull'}, 
    {'type': 'Format_Check', 'condition': 'isNum'}],
'emr_name': [
    {'type': 'Format_Check', 'condition': 'isStr'}]
```

**3. Let apply transformation on `raw_df` based on Entity_Set, Validation_Type, and Condition column.**

```
for column, validations in column_validations.items():
    
    # a. Iteration through columns, for example: identifier
    for validation in validations:
        # b. Iteration through validations,
        #    for example: {'type': 'Null_Check', 'condition': 'NotNull'}
        v_type, v_condition = [validation[key] for key in validation]

        # c. Transformations
        if v_type == "Null_Check":
            raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("comments", is_null_udf(column))
        elif v_type == "Format_Check" and v_condition == "isNum":
            raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("comments", is_digit_udf(column))
        elif v_type == "Format_Check" and v_condition == "isStr":
            raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("comments", is_string_udf(column))
```

**The complete code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# ------------UDFs------------
is_null_udf = udf(lambda value: 1 if value == None else 0)
is_digit_udf = udf(lambda value: 0 if str(value).isdigit() else 1)
is_string_udf = udf(lambda value: 0 if isinstance(value, str) else 1)

# ------------Validation Function------------
def perform_validation(entity):
    global raw_df
    
    entity_validations = val_df.filter(col("Entity") == entity).drop("Entity").collect()
    
    column_validations = {}
    for row in entity_validations:
        row_dict = row.asDict()
        val_column, val_type, val_condition = [row_dict[key] for key in row_dict]
        
        if val_column not in column_validations:
            column_validations[val_column] = []
            
        column_validations[val_column].append({'type': val_type, 'condition': val_condition})
            
    for column, validations in column_validations.items():
        for validation in validations:
            v_type, v_condition = [validation[key] for key in validation]         
            
            if v_type == "Null_Check":
                raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("comments", is_null_udf(column))
            elif v_type == "Format_Check" and v_condition == "isNum":
                raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("comments", is_digit_udf(column))
            elif v_type == "Format_Check" and v_condition == "isStr":
                print(column)
                raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("comments", is_string_udf(column))
        
        
perform_validation(entity="ADT")

raw_df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Final Output:**

```
+------------+----------+--------+--------+
|entityFamily|identifier|emr_name|comments|
+------------+----------+--------+--------+
|1           |8881      |emr_1   |0       |
|2           |8882      |emr_2   |0       |
+------------+----------+--------+--------+
```